# iPhone: Icon extension error in the archive validation

Tags: icons, ios4

Using the Xcode 3.2.3 I updated my app to iOS4 and build an archive.
When I tried to validate the application I received these warnings:

"Icon specified in the Info.plist CFBundleIconFile does not have an extension: icon"

Since my app is a universal app I have 4 icons mentioned in the plist and therefore 4 errors. I will also point out that in my plist the icons appear under CFBundleIconFiles and not CFBundleIconFile.

It is a known fact that it is better not to write the extensions of the icons otherwise the automatic retina display image choosing mechanism won't kick in and take the proper iPhone4 @2x icons.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Solution here (mostly):

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/8/4/application-icon-troubles.html

However, he was wrong on one point: in addition to the `CFBundleIconFiles` array, you *still* do need a `CFBundleIconFile` key with just the name of the 57x57 png file in it (e.g. *just* `icon.png`) in order to support backwards compatibility with pre-iOS4 devices. Otherwise, Application Loader will be a bitch and refuse to let you upload it.

Answer (score 0):

You should write file extensions, @2x images are loaded automatically with- or without extension.

Comment: Not in my experience. We needed to explicitly add Icon.png and Icon@2x.png.

Answer (score 0):

To save you some reading time on Chris Redfords link:

You need the following entries in info plist:
CFBundleIconFile with the name of the 57x57 png file (e.g. icon.png)
CFBundleIconFiles Array with one row containing the name of the file without extensions (e.g icon)